# How to convert float type nan in a dictionary value to 0.50?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as below:

```
{
   '$175000-199999': nan,
   '$698506': nan
}
```

I want to convert the nan to 0.50. I tried using dictionary comprehensions
`{k:v is 0.50 if v == nan else v for (k, v) in dictionary.items()}` but it throws an error saying nan is float. How do I fix this?

Comment: See if [this](https://trinket.io/python/d621a67d4c) snippet can help you.

Comment: that worked - Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values), here's a running example to solve your problem,

```
nan_obj = float( 'nan' )

# dict as mentioned in the question
dictionary = {
   '$175000-199999': nan_obj,
   '$698506': nan_obj
}

# Loop through key-value pairs
# For different ways to check if a number is NaN, 
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values
for key , value in dictionary.items():
    if value != value:
        dictionary[ key ] = 0.5
        
print( dictionary )
```